# A basis for the 0-Hecke ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, coxeter-groups, schubert-calculus

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter system of type $A_n$, with
$$S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$$
satisfying the usual relations, and let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]$ be a polynomial ring. $W$ acts on $R$ by extending to automorphisms the action
$$w(x_i)=x_{w(i)}$$
Let $F$ be the field of fractions of $R$; the action on $R$ extends to an action on $F$. We define the skew group ring to be the smash product of $\mathbb{Z}[W]$ with $F$, so that if $p\in F$, then
$$wp = (w(p))w$$
For an integer $1\leq i\leq n$, define
$$\partial^i=\frac{1}{x_i-x_{i+1}}(1-s_i)$$
Then consider the subring $\mathcal{N}$ generated by all $s_i$ and $\partial^j$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$.

I can prove that $\mathcal{N}$ is spanned by "reduced expressions", which would be products of $\partial^i$ and $s_j$ such that if you replace each $\partial^i$ with $s_i$, they would become reduced expressions for the corresponding element in $W$. However, they do not at all form a basis. For example,
$$\partial^1s_2\partial^1=s_2\partial^1\partial^2+\partial^2\partial^1s_2$$
We can also derive from this the equation
$$s_1\partial^2\partial^1=\partial^2\partial^1s_2 + \partial^1\partial^2$$
and other basis-killing equations.

I am familiar with results about the ring generated by all $s_i$ and $\pi_j$, where
$$\pi_j=\partial^jx_j,$$
which has a very nice and easy to describe basis, but I was unable to find one for this $0$-Hecke ring. Does anyone have any ideas about a basis for $\mathcal{N}$?

I worked out a basis for $n=2$, which I will include here. Degree $0$ has rank $6$, which are just the group elements. Degree $1$ has
$$\partial^1,\partial^2,s_1\partial^2,s_2\partial^1,\partial^1s_2,\partial^2s_1,s_1s_2\partial^1,s_2s_1\partial^2,s_1\partial^2s_1$$
and hence has rank $9$. Degree $2$ is where relations start to kick in, and we have the basis
$$s_1\partial^2\partial^1,s_2\partial^1\partial^2,\partial^1\partial^2s_1,\partial^2\partial^1s_2$$
and hence degree $2$ has rank $4$ (notice $\partial^1\partial^2$ and $\partial^2\partial^1$ do not appear at all). Degree $3$ has only $\partial^1\partial^2\partial^1$ and hence has rank $1$. Hence $\mathcal{N}$ for $n=2$ has rank $20$.